# Actionscript - Detect simple shape in Image

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, webcam, detection

I wonder if it's possible to detect a simple shape like a circle or a rectangle in an image with ActionScript 3. Can somebody guide me into the right direction or even give me a link to a good tutorial? I want to detect a logo with the webcam. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible I did a ball detecting algorythm for a video. Once you access the bitmap  each frame, (ex. a vector>, where uint is the color of the pixyel in vector[x][y]), it is only universal detection algorithms. Hugh transform, etc.. So you go ahead, and detect rectangles. There are lots of [tutorials.](https://www.google.at/search?client=opera&q=rectangle%20detection&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) Its high math.. There is also [FLARManager](http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/), what can detect cool qr codes in Flash. Lee Brimelow did a great [video tutorial](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=114) of it.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. I also found a great tutorial from adobe  using the flartoolkit: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/augmented_reality.html